# Does Safari handle the paste event correctly?

Tags: javascript, safari, dom-events

I'm trying to write some code for Safari for handling the 'paste' event, but it doesn't seem to work right.  According to the WebKit DOM reference, `oncut`, `onpaste`, and `oncopy` are all handled more-or-less like the W3C Clipboard API suggests.  However, it doesn't work like I expect.  I'm pasting image data, but as far as I've been able to tell, the problem I'm having applies to any kind of paste.  This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XdTea/6/) works just fine in Chrome, but not in Safari 6.0.4 on OSX.

```
$(function () {
    console.log("ready");
    $("#pastearea").on("paste", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.debug("testing paste in safari");
        var blob = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items[0].getAsFile();
        console.debug(blob);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = readerLoaded;

        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
});

function readerLoaded(e) {
    $("#dest").attr("src", e.target.result);
}
```

I tried again using just [plain JS](http://jsfiddle.net/XdTea/10/).  Still no joy:

```
<div id="pastearea" onpaste="plainjsOnPaste()" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: blue;"/>

function plainjsOnPaste(e) {
    console.log("blahblahblah");
    console.log(e);   
}
```

If there's some issue with Safari, then obviously I shouldn't expect jQuery to work.  As far as I can tell, in the second attempt (plain) I'm doing exactly what the WebKit reference suggests I should do, but it doesn't work at all.  Is this some known limitation of Safari, or is the problem between the chair and keyboard?

*Update*: it seems that Safari doesn't implement the W3C's working draft of the Clipboard APIs.  I'm researching workarounds, but if anyone knows one I'd love to heard it.

Comment: It seems Safari needs some sort of input area where you can make the paste happen, using `contentEditable=true` will trigger the event in Safari http://jsfiddle.net/RrP8X/

Comment: @Duopixel why a comment and not an answer?  That's a perfectly valid  answer (even better if you can cite a source for that...)

Comment: It would also be preferable to do this without setting contentEditable - this has some undesirable side-effects, such as showing a textarea cursor on focus.

Comment: It's not an answer precisely because it's not an ideal solution. Just meant to set you in the right direction. I have the time to help but not the time to solve. Good luck!

Comment: @Duopixel fair enough.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer, as unsatisfying as it might be, is "no". See this WebKit bug:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75891

If your intention is to receive paste data into something that's not contentEditable, a text input or a text area, I don't know of any method to make the current version of Safari do this.

Update: an attempted work-around in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NayPk/11/), simplified to only deal with text, does not work in Safari 6.0.5. It attempts a work-around where a hidden text field is automatically focused when Cmd-V is pressed, just in order to enable pasting in Safari. It does prevent the "you can't paste beep", but no paste event is sent and nothing is pasted into the secret input.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).bind('keydown', function (e) {
        // Cmd-V
        if (e.which == 86 && e.metaKey) {
            if (e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "INPUT")
                $('#secretinput').focus();
        }
    });

    $(window).bind('beforepaste', function (e) {
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('paste', function (e) {
        var clipboardData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
        console.log(clipboardData);
        $('#textdest').html(clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
    });
});
```

Comment: @Juhana whoops looks like you copied in some code into this answer which I intentionally omitted from it. Feel free to write a new answer if you'd like to answer this in a different way than I did. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps you, but I use a out-of-screen input to force safari accept paste on the page. It helped me so here it goes:

I'm doing:

script:

```
$(document).bind('paste', function(e) {
    var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('Text');
    // here using data from clipboard
});

$(function(){
   $('input.special').focus();
});
```

css:

```
input.special{
position:absolute;
top:-40px;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="text" class="special" style="position: absolute;top:-40px;">
```