# Add text to clipboard in Safari desktop on Cmd+C

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, clipboard, draw.io

In Safari desktop `document.execCommand('copy')` doesn't work, so I'm struggling with adding a text in the clipboard on <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> key press

What I tried is to catch <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> combination on `keydown` event and do the following:

- create a hidden input with text I want to put in clipboard
- set focus to the input
- select the text in the input

but text is not copied to clipboard. This works however on Chrome for example.

The following question says it's not possible but I see apps like `draw.io` and others doing it, so there has to be a way:

[Does Safari handle the paste event correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930542/does-safari-handle-the-paste-event-correctly)

Answer (score -1):

It is actually quite difficult, not to say impossible, and hacky to modify the user's clipboard. Your try was nice but I think your selection is overriden each time by the user's. 
What you may want to try is to modify the text on detection of Cmd/Ctrl+C and then restore it.

More details available here : [How does Trello access the user's clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527870/how-does-trello-access-the-users-clipboard)

Comment: I don't understand what you said. And I was aware of that question too. The solution doesn't work on Safari.