# jquery paste image not working safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am using a text editor its working fine on paste image in all browsers but not in safari.
Here is my code to get the image on paste event

```
 $(".Editor-editor").bind("paste", function (event) {

       var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
        
        var blob = null;
        if (items[0].type.indexOf("image") != -1) {
            blob = items[0].getAsFile();
        }
           
        if (blob !== null) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = event.target.result;

                var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();
                range.insertNode(img);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `.bind` is a deprecated function do not use that!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping thanks i will change that but event is working in safari also

Comment: refer on this post [Safari paste event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930542/does-safari-handle-the-paste-event-correctly)

Comment: @ian there is no issue in text . its working fine but in image there is issue